# How to check if a certain file already exists in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on `symfony2`  and currently I want to check if a file does exist. My scenario look something like this,, I have two files `excel` file and the `docx` file. If a person have an `excel` file for her/his transaction then it is automatically that the `docx` file is not applicable for her or him.And vice versa. How can I possibly do it in `symfony2`? A lot in the net but I don't know how to do it in my case,, thanks a lot :)

**UPDATE**
Controller:

```
public function documentType ($doc_type) {
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
   $result = $em->getRepository('SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetails')->findDocumentType('xlsx');
   $result1 = $em->getRepository('SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetails')->findDocumentType('docx');
   // statement that will know if the file exists for that certain user if so the other document type will be not applicable for that user. Example: that user have docx file already then the xlsx will be N/A and vice versa

}
```

**Repository :**

```
public function findDocumentType ($doc_type) {
   $em = $this->getEntityManager();
   $query = $em->createQuery(
       'SELECT a, b, c FROM SupplierBundle:SupplierTransaction Details a
        JOIN a.supplierTransaction b
        JOIN b.supplierDocType c
        WHERE c.docType LIKE :doc_type'
   )->setParameter('doc_type', $doc_type);

   return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: php [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) ?

Comment: @YenneInfo: how can I do it symfony? can you please give example on how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it the Symfony2 way, you can use the `Filesystem` class, it has an [`exists()`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem/introduction.html#exists) function. In a controller an instance is automatically available in the service container:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$xlsx = $em->getRepository('SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetail')->findDocumentType‌('xlsx');
$docx = $em->getRepository('SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetail')->findDocumnetType‌('docx');

return [
        'xlsx' => $xlsx instanceof SupplierTransactionDetail && $this->get('filesystem')->exists($xlsx->getFile()) ? $xlsx->getFile() : null,
        'docx' => $docx instanceof SupplierTransactionDetail && $this->get('filesystem')->exists($docx->getFile()) ? $docx->getFile() : null,
    ];
```

In your twig template:

```
{% if xlsx is not empty %}
    {{ xlsx }}
{% endif %}

{% if docx is not empty %}
    {{ docx }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: is it okay to render in my repository and just store it in a variable?

Comment: example I have something like this : `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $result = $em->getRepository('SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetail')->findDocumentType('xlsx');
        $result1 = $em->getRepository('SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetail')->findDocumnetType('docx');`

Comment: You will have to do the `exists` test in the controller and then yes, pass variables to your view so you can display the correct information to the user.

Comment: how can I do it in the controller if  that file already exist then  the other one will be N\A , can you give an example using the code I just pasted a while ago?

Comment: I'm not totally sure to understand what you want, answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use plain PHP for this. For example:

```
$xls = 'sheet.xlsx';
$doc = 'document.docx';

if (file_exists($xls)) {
    // User has an XLSX file
    echo 'Download your sheet <a href="sheet.xlsx">here</a>.';
} elseif (file_exists($doc)) {
    // User has a DOCX file
    echo 'Download your document <a href="document.docx">here</a>.';
}
```

Comment: can you convert it to symfony?

Comment: @Errorhere There is no need for that, Symfony is still just PHP and you can just use plain commands like file_exists anywhere in it's codebase.